# Number of values returned in DirSync multi-valued attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

By experiment, using **DirSync**, I found the maximum number of values returned from a multi-valued attribute is **5000**.

This does not seem affected by the MaxValRange LDAP policy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223376.aspx), neither the Page size (it must be 0 for DirSync to work).

Currently I handle the issue by checking if there are 5000 (determined by a registry) values returned for a attribute. If yes, I will do a range-retrieval on it.

My questions are:

- Is this number (5000) configurable?
- If yes, how?
- If not, will this number varies on different OS (or domain/forest functional level)?
  Can I read it some where though I can't modify it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223347.aspx and see if that helps. If you can use Incremental values?